# Who is responsible for loading data?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a constructor signature that looks like this.

```
public LocateEditorViewModel(
    ILocateRepository locateRepository, 
    int id, 
    IInteractionService interactionService)
{
```

As the class name suggests this is the view model I use to edit locates. This view model is created from a factory that injects `ILocateRepository` and `IInteractionService`. The id is passed in the factories `Create(int id)` function.

Is it the job of the `LocateEditorViewModel` to receive and `id` of the item I wish to edit and query it from the database. Or should I query for the given item in my factory and replace my `int id` parameter into a `LocateViewModel` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ViewModel works on the data of the Model which in turn accesses the database. The ViewModel does not access the database.
So: Yes, you should replace the id with the actual object.